# Javascript createDocumentFragment()

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding createDocumentFragment() in the following example:

```html
<p>Click the button to make changes to a list item, using the createDocumentFragment method, then appending the list item as the last child of the list.</p>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var d = document.createDocumentFragment();
    d.appendChild(document.getElementsByTagName("LI")[0]);
    d.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Milk";
    document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].appendChild(d);
  }
</script>
```

from: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_createdocfrag

Why is it `childNodes[0].childNodes[0]` instead of just one `childNodes[0]`?

Comment: It's the first child of the first child instead of just the first child ;-) childNodes is an array containing all __direct__ child nodes.

Comment: Post the code you have a question about here, in case w3schools changes.

Comment: The first node child is the LI, the first Node of the LI is a text node.

Answer (score 3):

`childNodes` is a [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-536297177) (behaving very much like an array) containing all the **direct** descendants of a particular node.

Imagine a structure like this:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="a_0">
        <div id="a_0_0"></div>
        <div id="a_0_1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="a_1"></div>
</div>
```

Now, a call to `document.getElementById("a")` would return the outermost node.

```
var a = document.getElementById("a");

console.log(a.childNodes[0].id); // would show "a_0"       
console.log(a.childNodes[1].id); // would show "a_1"     
console.log(a.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].id); // would show "a_0_0"
```

Additionally, text within a node is again a separate node (a [Text node](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772)).

So imagine a structure like this:

```
<div id="a">This is some text</div>
```

Then, again using the example above, you need to access the text like this:

```
var a = document.getElementById("a");
console.log(a.data) // Will log "undefined"
console.log(a.childNodes[0].data) // Will log "This is some text"
```

Instead of `childNodes[0]`, you can take the shortcut `firstChild`, which returns the same result.

This behavior of treating text nodes as separate nodes is necessary, because of the following scenario:

```
<div id="a">This text contains <strong>strong</strong> text</div>
```

Here, the node `a` has three child nodes: A text node ("This text contains"), a `strong`-node, and an appending text node again ("text"). The `strong`-node contains one text node ("strong"). Because these elements reside on the same level in the document hierarchy, they have to be separated from each other.

Comment: Actually your first example is wrong. In your markup there are new-line characters and white space ones for indentation, which constitute an textNode and which doesn't have an id...

Comment: Not necessarily. If you treated my example as the HTML source, you'd be right. In fact, I just visualized the structure and used some formatting for better readability. Thus, it's not wrong.

Comment: Yes it is wrong, we've got no way to know what you did "for readibility". What you pasted is an HTML sample, and this sample does contains the white spaces I mentionned. It's a common mistake to not take these chatacters as textNodes when writing HTML, and dealing with childNodes, and nowhere in your answer do you speak about it.

Comment: You have everything you need: I wrote "imagine a __structure__ like this...", not "imagine an HTML source like this". So I Made clear I'm speaking about the structure, not the source. And just you wanting it to be wrong doesn't actually make it wrong ;) So it is ok for me when you say it is wrong __in your opinion__